# Why is my webs scraping function returning something unexpected?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal: Attempting to build a function; `def retrieve_title(html)` that expects as input, a string of html and returns the title element.

I've imported beautifulsoup to complete this task. Any guidance is appreciated as I'm still learning.

My attempted function:

```
def retrieve_title(html):
    soup = [html]
    result = soup.title.text
    return(result)
```

Using the function:

```
html = '<title>Jack and the bean stalk</title><header>This is a story about x y z</header><p>talk to you later</p>'
print(get_title(html))
```

Unexpected outcome:

> "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'"

Expected outcome:

> "Jack and the beanstalk"

Comment: How are you _using_ this function?

Comment: I will be running the function at a later date to pull out the titles from a bunch of different strings (of html), and of course where no titles are present, raise a ValueError

Comment: But how do you call it now, not what are you going to do in the future? How did you get this error message?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clearer - I hope this helps

Comment: Replace `soup = [html]` with `soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Jack and the bean stalk` is a text node immediate after `title tag` so to grab that  you can apply `.find(text=True)`

```
 html = '''
    <title>
     Jack and the beanstalk     
    </title>
    <header>
     This is a story about x y z
    </header>
    <p>
     Once upon a time
    </p>
    '''
    
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    
    #print(soup.prettify())
    
    title=soup.title.find(text=True)
    print(title)
```

**Output:**

```
 Jack and the beanstalk
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function

```py
print(retrieve_title(html))
```

Comment: Did you call your function by passing it an argument, `html variable` in your case ?